# Add HTML source code into CkEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to design the email in CKEditor in my application, it works like charm when we design it manually, now we have complicated html source code, instead of designing the mail structure manually, I need to add the available HTML Source code into CKEditor,

```
<body>
<table>
....
</table>

</body>
```

[image]

I will need to add the above html code into CKEditor, Please can anyone help me to get this !!!

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: I need a way to insert directly html code into CkEditor

Comment: is there any plugin to add html code into ckEditor ?

Comment: you have to bind it on CkEditor config initially

Comment: I have added screen capture

Comment: You have to make custom tool box for that. check http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Custom-Toolbar-Configuration